# The Region $R$ is bounded by the curves $ y=x^2+1$, and $y=3x-1$.

Tags: calculus

The Region $R$ is bounded by the curves$ y=x^2+1$, and $y=3x-1$.

Set up two integrals (method of washers and method of shells) for the volume of the solid obtained by rotating $R$ around the line x=4. Use one of these to compute the volume.

I am not sure how to look at problem such as this. Is my set up okay?

What should I do next?

[image]

Comment: Your sketch currently suggests that the axis of revolution is the line $y=0$ (the $x$ axis), not the (vertical line) $x=4$. Also, the radii for the washer setup will be functions of $y$, not $x$.

Answer (score 1):

First note that
$$\begin{cases}y=3x-1\\y=x^2+1\end{cases}\iff~\begin{cases}x=\dfrac{y+1}{3}\\[1ex]x=\sqrt{y-1}\end{cases}$$
with intersection points $(1,2)$ and $(2,5)$.

Using washers, the outer radius of any cross-section of the solid perpendicular to the axis of revolution would be $4-\dfrac{y+1}{3}$, and the inner radius would be $4-\sqrt{y-1}$. So, the volume would be given by
$$\pi\int_2^5\left(\left(4-\frac{y+1}{3}\right)^2-\left(4-\sqrt{y-1}\right)^2\right)\,\mathrm{d}y$$
Using shells, the setup is somewhat simpler. Each shell has a height determined by the vertical distance between the curves at a given point $x$, ie. $(3x-1)-(x^2+1)=-x^2+3x-2$. The radius of each shell is the horizontal distance from a given point $x$ within the interval $[1,2]$ to the axis of revolution, ie. $4-x$. The volume is then also given by the integral
$$2\pi\int_1^2(4-x)(-x^2+3x-2)\,\mathrm{d}x$$
I leave the choice of which integral to compute to you.